# PySpark - Connect to s3 - read a file to rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Am trying to connect to my s3 bucket using pyspark.
Below is the code:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

AWS_KEY = '...'
AWS_SECRET = '...'

aws_connection = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)
bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('activitylogs-prod')

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", AWS_KEY)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", AWS_SECRET)

print len(list(bucket.list()))
for key in bucket.list():
    file_name = 's3n://myBucket/'+key.name
    print file_name
    rdd = sc.textFile(file_name 
        ,'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat',
        'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
        'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable'
        )
    print rdd.count()
```

It throws an exception saying:

```
textFile() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Previously it used to throw something like:

```
 "s3n" not recognized
```

**Am using, Spark 1.6 & Hadoop 2.6**

I've checked many threads on SO but nothing seems to work in my case.

Any suggestion on how to deal with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`textFile` only takes a path and `minPartitions` (optionally), I think what you are looking for is `hadoopFile`...which does take the different Format classes.

Comment: I've tried using hadoopFile, but it throws "An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.hadoopFile.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n"

Comment: That is a known issue with Hadoop modularization -> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7442 You need to include the appropriate files and settings to get this to work in Spark...it's just not built in any longer